# Finding out what happens on the boundary of the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n\ln^2n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am working on a problem that asks for the radius of convergence of the following sequence in the complex plane: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n\ln^2n}$$

With the root test I managed to find that $R=1$ so convergence is guaranteed for $|z|<1$. How do I determine if the convergence occurs for the values of $|z|=1$. Obviously it converges for $z = \pm 1$ but what about the complex values of $|z|=1$. Can anyone provide some insight/help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^{2}(n)}$ converges by Cauchy's Condensation test .
So as $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\lvert\frac{z^{n}}{n\ln^{2}(n)}\rvert\leq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^{2}(n)}\,\,\forall |z|\leq 1$

It follows that the series is convergent $\forall |z|\leq 1$. Note that Direct comparison of series is always allowed regardless of whether it is complex or real.

Does this sufficiently answer your question

Answer (score 3):

I will give an alternate method to Arghyadeep. To check whether $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/n\ln^2(n)$ converges, by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) it suffices to show $\int_2^\infty1/x\ln^2(x)dx$ converges. Now, we have:

\begin{align*}
\int_2^\infty\frac1{x\ln^2(x)}dx&=\int_2^\infty\frac1{\ln^2(x)}d\ln(x)\\
&=\left[-\frac1{\ln(x)}\right]_2^\infty\\
&=\frac1{\ln(2)}.\\
\end{align*}